# Relink Access tables to a SQL Server that is not available

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I wrote a function to relink SQL Server tables in an Access app. That works great, except if I want to change the `.connect` property to a server where I have no access.  In that case, the `tableDef.Refresh` generates an error.
Is there a trick I could use to relink from DEV to PROD **before deployment** when I have no access to PROD ?
I thought about replacing all linked tables pointing to SQL Server by Passthru queries (`select * from tableX`). Any other idea ?

Comment: but you know the PROD server details beforehand right?

Comment: @krishKM: yes I know the PROD server details, and I checked my code is running ok with a PROD user.

Comment: I think it could be a good request for the Access Suggestion Box for a next release. http://access.uservoice.com/

Answer (score 2):

Access will not `RefreshLink` a link whose `Connect` property points to a data source which is unavailable.  That limitation applies not just to server database data sources, but any type of data source.

Create a function you call from an *AutoExec* macro which checks whether the application is running the first time in the PROD context.  And if it is, set the linked tables `Connect` properties and call `RefreshLink`.